# Не импортируется пакет openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

Делаю по документации https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/

установил через pip install openpyxl

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
```

и не импортируется:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/OneDrive/WORC/Python/bitrix24/report/openpyxl.py", line 3, in <module>
    from openpyxl import Workbook
  File "D:\OneDrive\WORC\Python\bitrix24\report\openpyxl.py", line 3, in <module>
    from openpyxl import Workbook
ImportError: cannot import name 'Workbook'
```

пробывал заменить Workbook на workbook и все равно не работает

версия openpyxl -   2.4.5
python  - 3.6.0

Comment: Сначачала запустите `pip freeze` и проверьте действительно ли установлен openpyxl. `Затем C:/OneDrive/WORC/Python/Scripts/pip.exe freeze` и снова убедитесь, что библиотека там. Еще можно проверить, что конкретно вы запускаете командой `where pip`. Библиотека могла установиться на какой-нибудь другой интерпретатор, который лежит в другом месте. На будущее можно посмотреть на virtualenv, чтобы избегать путаницы.

Comment: у вас файл назван `openpyxl.py` что конфликтует с одноимённым Питон-пакетом.

Answer (score 0):

да через pip freeze вижу что openpyxl установлен, все это дело у меня изначально было на virtualenv, другие пакеты установленные в этом же virtualenv работают

в общем решил проблему скачав openpyxl и положив его в папку с проектом.